# Linux server as router - issue

Tags: fedora, iptables, virtualbox, routing, nat

I am fairly new to Linux and I'm trying to test a few things on my environment.
I set up a Linux server (fedora) in order to connect 2 networks.
The server has a third natted nic (shared with my host through virtualbox).
I can successfully browse from the linux server, but if I try and ping 8.8.8.8 or similar from any client, it doesn't work.
Default route on the client is in place; iptables are allowing icmp.

What am I missing?

Comment: So you're dealing with a VM host with 3 NICs, a VM on it, two different networks and you expect us to solve anything without providing any detailed information whatsoever.  What are those networks, is the VM the machine that acts as a router for outside connections?  What is the network configuration of every machine mentioned?  What are your routing tables?  How does the VM get access to the network?  Is it maybe bridged or NATed?  When you say `Default route on the client is in place`, what is the client and does it mean that there exists a universal default route that you can be sure works?

Comment: You have a **lot** of experimenting and learning ahead of you.

Comment: Correct, the VM acts as a router. The NIC that provides internet connectivity is configured as NAT through virtualbox. The other 2 NICs are configured as internal network. They are 192.168.1.X and 192.168.2.X (standard /24 netmask). Client machines are 192.168.1.10 and 2.20

Comment: fossil's answer might be enough to get it working, but too much information is missing to be sure.  How does the traffic get routed through the VM?  Does that VM act as the default gateway for the two networks?

Comment: Yes the router is the default getaway for both networks. I am very sorry I couldn't take my laptop with me, so I'm trying to give you all the info i can remember on top of my mind. I know its not much to work with. This is going to bug me all night.

Comment: Please put that information into your question, where (a) it can be decently laid out and formatted, and (b) we can see it and understand it clearly and easily.

Answer (score 2):

As commented above, we could have done better with more information. The solution suggested below expects the `iptables` has been setup to allow in/out traffic. Anyway, you may be missing two things.

You need to explicitly allow forwarding of traffic. You need to modify /etc/sysctl.conf` add the following line.

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Also, you need to masquerade the outgoing traffic. Masquerading rewrites the outgoing IP address of all packets to the host having additional nic with NAT. You can enable masquerading as shown below. Watch out for the NAT interface name.

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Replace `eth0` with the name of your NAT interface.**

**Troubleshooting Tips**

1. Ping the Linux server`s host interface address from client(s). If
   success, clients are able to reach the default gateway.
2. Ping the Linux server's nat interface address from client(s). If
   successful, `iptables firewall` is allowing the ICMP traffic. If
   not, you need to check on `iptables firewall` configuration.
3. Once you are done with above steps, the only things left out are `outgoing rules` and `postrouting masquerade`. You may have to check it out again.

Comment: Thanks fossil. Ip_forward is enabled and so is masquerade. I have added a logging rule in the iptables (to try and troubleshoot a little deeper) and I see this:    ... IN = OUT SRC: 10.X.X.X DST: 8.8.8.8 prot: icmp DROP when I try pinging from one of the 2 clients. When I ping the Google DNS from the server all is good.

Comment: Could you paste the outputs of `iptables -L -n` and `iptables -L -n -t nat`

Comment: I would add `-v` to your `iptables` commands to get a more complete output.

Comment: @Dave:  If you see that ICMP packets are dropped, then iptables is not allowing icmp as mentioned in the question.  Does browsing work?

Comment: Browsing on the router yes, browsing on the client no. It looks like the packet is forwarded correctly from the client nic to its default getaway (router 192.168.1.x), then it reaches the nat interface through the default route on the router... but its dropped. I confirmed with a quick tcpdump I see the echo requests coming on the NAT interface on the router. But I do not understand what happens after. As soon as possible I will get you the iptables full output.

Comment: @Dave If you see the packets coming on to NAT interface, check out the outgoing rules and also masquerade configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You guys were right.
I was missing the POSTROUTING masquerade and the forward as shown here below:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE 
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```